# how to trigger a function inside another function using HTTP get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, websocket

I have the socketController function and I wanted to call it inside the summation function so that every time I did the GET of the summation func, the socketcontroller function would be triggered. Is it possible to do this? The sum func console.log is giving UNDEFINED

controller.js

```
module.exports = {
      async socketController(client) {
        return client.send('mandando algo pro cliente');
      },
    
      async somatoria(request, response, socketController) {
        console.log(socketController);
        return response.json(socketController);
      }
}
```

server.js

```
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    socketController(client);
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
```

console.log return:

[Function: next]

Comment: Why `async`? you're not using `await` inside your function, so it's useless

Comment: Also you did not import anything from `controller.js`. You need to `import { socketController } from "controller.js"`

Comment: Hey Jeremy, I imported {socketController }but didn't put the rest of the code. Thanks